# Which is Fastest way to access SQLCE(Microsoft Sql Compact Edition) Database in Windows CE mobile(OS Windows CE))?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, windows, sql-server-ce

I have 3000+ record in my database and I want to Display that record in my Windows CE mobile application.Which is Fastest way to Display that record.I used C# language.How can I do that?

Comment: You need to be more precise about your question by providing more info.

Comment: What are you asking? how to retrieve the data from the database? how to make a UI? you need to write provide more information, if you want a useful answer.

Comment: I used windows CE mobile and it's memory low and my database is huge almost 3000+ record and When i displayed record it's time consuming process any other way to display record in my application.

Comment: I tried Window CE os --- XML(Middle) --- SQL compact edition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689455/what-is-the-fast-way-for-find-data-in-sqlce-windows-mobile-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MS artice discusses this exact topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938877.aspx

I was using table adapers and it was really, really slow. One operation wrote 3000 records of about 50 chars and took 20-30 minutes on an old win ce 6.1 device.

I changed over to use resultsets and same task is about 1-2 minutes.

Andrew